# how to extract image link with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, element

I am trying to get a link from a weboage HTML in python. the problem is that when I open the chrome inspect tool, I can see that the link is like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/09edc9a95239bbd46cbf5d2f344fc45620166666_1620816530.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_350,w_350/quality,q_60">
```

But, when I get the HTML using this code, this line doesn't exist in the HTML.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
 
url = 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-729879/%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%86%D8%AE-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%81-%DA%A9%D8%AF-1312-%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%87-3-%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF%DB%8C/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
req = Request(url,headers=headers)
webpage = str(urlopen(req).read())
print(webpage)
```

The HTML that I get from python seems to be a lot shorter and doesn't contain this element at all.
what I want to know is, how can I get that element through python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags you see are created programmatically via Javascript that loads the data from different URL. This example will use `requests`/`json` module to get the data:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-729879/%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%86%D8%AE-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%81-%DA%A9%D8%AF-1312-%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%87-3-%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF%DB%8C/"

id_ = re.search(r"-(\d+)/", url).group(1)
product_url = f"https://api.digikala.com/v1/product/{id_}/"
data = requests.get(product_url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["data"]["seo"]["open_graph"]["image"])
```

Prints:

```
https://dkstatics-public.digikala.com/digikala-products/113697641.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_350,w_350/quality,q_60
```

Answer (score 1):

The page has a js rendering so the html returned by the query should be evaluated as javascript. Like a browser does!

Try to use a splash docker and send the request througth it and should work or use another tool that works similarly.

[Link to Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)